# Getting a 404 page not found error for every page other than /

Tags: apache2

If I go to my [server's IP](http://134.213.177.96), the homepage comes up fine.

However, If I try to navigate to say, [the about page](http://134.213.177.96/about), I get:

```
404 Not Found The requested URL /about was not found on this server.
```

Can someone please help me figure out why this is happening? I'm using Apache on Ubuntu.

Comment: Can you please post the output of `ls /var/www/html`?

Comment: the output is my huge laravel app and the html standard ubuntu page

Comment: it works fine on my local machine i check it and work great

Comment: Not sure if you changed anything, but now I can get to the /about page just fine...

Comment: Yes thank you Android Dev it was just permission on the Ubuntu page thanks